# Problem with validating data in Form Request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a form in Laravel blade and I am having trouble with validating data. I validated data from my controller with $request->validate(['some_data' => 'some_value']) as an example. I put that in variable $validatedData and I use that variable bellow in session put method and in fill method and it worked fine. What I did is tried to refactor code and I put that validation in FormRequest and removed variable $validatedData and put $request instead of it. When I did that then it showed an error

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::fill() must be of the type array, object given
```

and it breaks down because now $request now isn't an array like it was before, it is an object instead. How should I fix that to work? Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

Controller

```
public function postStepOne(FirstFormRequest $request)
{
    // $validatedData = $request->validate(['some_data' => 'some_value', etc.]);

    if(empty($request->session()->get('questionnaire'))){
        $questionnaire = new Questionnaire();
        $questionnaire->fill($request); IT WAS $validatedData BEFORE
        $request->session()->put('questionnaire', $questionnaire);
    } else {
        $questionnaire = $request->session()->get('questionnaire');
        $questionnaire->fill($request); // IT WAS $validatedData BEFORE
        $questionnaire->session()->put('questionnaire', $questionnaire);
    }

    return redirect()->route('questionnaires.create.step.two');
}
```

FirstFormRequest

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
      'business' => 'required',
      'residing' => 'required|in:yes,no',
      'different_address' => 'required_if:residing,yes',
      'business_address' => 'required_if:different_address,no',
      'company_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    ];
}
```

Comment: do you only want to pass the "validated" fields to `fill(...)` or all the possible inputs of the request?

Comment: @lagbox I want to pass validated fields to fill method

Comment: are you purposefully not saving the model?

Comment: @lagbox Yes I am.

Comment: $request is an object of FirstFormRequest class - hence the error. You are trying to pass $request object to the fill method. You should do `$questionnaire->fill($request->all())` or `$questionnaire->fill($request->validated())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the validated inputs from the Form Request with the `validated` method:

```
$questionnaire->fill($request->validated());
```

You can do the initialization and filling in one statement though:

```
$questionnaire = new Questionnaire($request->validated());
```

Comment: Yes, that's it it works, thank you! Only one more thing regarding one statment initialization and filling that you wrote. Can I call new Questionnaire class with just 'new self'?

Comment: if you were in the context of the Model class yes, but you are doing this from a Controller (outside the model)

Comment: Yes, I do it from controller but I call in construct method QuestionnaireRepository which calls Questionnaire model